# Delay Between Mail Receive in Exchange 2010 on SBS2011

Tags: email, exchange-2010, small-business-server

I've just migrated my servers from Exchange 2003, and decided to rather use SBS 2011 with Exchange 2010.

Some users are complaining about the delay between mail collection. I set the pop connector to 5 minutes, I could override this, But I've read that if the mail is large it can fail if the collection time is to short.

Is there any way to receive mail quicker?

Comment: Are your mail clients connecting via POP3 (as the connector's name implies) or IMAP? IMAP tends to work better for large mail files and deeply nested folder structures. POP3 frequently fails to keep message state (unread/read) and prefers the mailbox size to be kept to a minimum to ensure speed response.

Answer (score 0):

Point your MX records to your SBS Exchange server.  To do this make an A record for your public IP such as mail.yourdomain.com then make an MX record pointing to mail.yourdomain.com.